# Sumar tuplas de dos en dos

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, python-requests

Dada una tupla que contenga muchas tuplas como la siguiente: `a = ((45, 4), (43,20), (84, 30), (95, 7), (41, 45), (20, 46))`, necesito crear una función que me devuelva una tupla de tuplas, sumando, de dos en dos, las tuplas contenidas en la tupla original.

El resultado de esta función al ejemplo anterior (a) debería ser el siguiente:

```
res = ((88, 24), (179, 37), (61, 91))
```

Comment: Podrías agregar el código que hiciste hasta ahora por favor? Así tu pregunta no parecerá del tipo "haganme la tarea"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es algo tan facil y hay varias maneras de hacerlo pere aqui tienes un ejemplo:

```
a = ((45, 4), (43,20), (84, 30), (95, 7), (41, 45), (20, 46))

def sumando_de_dos_en_dos(tuplas):

    sumas = []
    num_tuplas = len(tuplas)
    if num_tuplas % 2 != 0:
        raise ValueError('El numero de tuplas debe ser un numero par')
    else:
        for i in range(0, num_tuplas, 2):
            a, b = tuplas[i]
            a_, b_ = tuplas[i+1]
            sumas.append((a + a_, b + b_))
    return tuple(sumas)
```

Este produce:

```
((88, 24), (179, 37), (61, 91))
```

Desculpe mi espanol muy mal!